# Hibernate and Query with criteria No value specified for parameter 2

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I don't know why, but I do face the exception everytime when I try to put more than one parameter to method for extract sorted data from database. What I want to do is extract data from one entity and from another entity depends on criteria, using Query with criteria.

The error occurs like this:

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [app-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@1fdc6f6: startup date [Wed May 22 11:06:19 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [connection.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3b8d23: defining beans [dataSource,transactionManager,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,daoInsertDataInterface,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,sessionFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Hibernate: select this_.DATE_ID as DATE1_1_1_, this_.CHILD_ADMISSION_DATE as CHILD2_1_1_, this_.CHILD_GO_SCHOOL_DATE as CHILD3_1_1_, this_.PARTICULAR_DATE as PARTICULAR4_1_1_, this_.VERSION as VERSION1_1_, schedulero2_.DATE_ID as DATE1_1_3_, schedulero3_.SRC_ID as SRC2_3_, schedulero3_.SRC_ID as SRC1_2_0_, schedulero3_.CHILD_ADMITTED as CHILD2_2_0_, schedulero3_.CHILD_GO_SCHOOL as CHILD3_2_0_, schedulero3_.CHILD_UNDER_3_YEARSOLD as CHILD4_2_0_, schedulero3_.CHILD_UPPER_3_YEARSOLD as CHILD5_2_0_, schedulero3_.DAY_SCHEDULE as DAY6_2_0_, schedulero3_.NUMBER_OF_CHILD as NUMBER7_2_0_, schedulero3_.ROTATION as ROTATION2_0_, schedulero3_.VERSION as VERSION2_0_, schedulero3_.WORK_SCHEDULE as WORK10_2_0_ from CREATION_DATE this_ left outer join SRC_DATE schedulero2_ on this_.DATE_ID=schedulero2_.DATE_ID left outer join SCHEDULE_ROTATION_CHILD schedulero3_ on schedulero2_.SRC_ID=schedulero3_.SRC_ID where (this_.PARTICULAR_DATE=? and this_.DATE_ID=?)
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07001
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No value specified for parameter 2
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at edu.demidov.dao.InsertDataService.findByDateAndType(InsertDataService.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy24.findByDateAndType(Unknown Source)
    at edu.demidov.dao.AppTEst.main(AppTEst.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2611)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2586)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2510)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2259)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    ... 20 more
```

My DAO method:

```
@Override
public List<CreationDate> findByDateAndType() throws HibernateException, ParseException {

    Criterion bydate = Restrictions.eq("particularDate", AppTEst.addMyDate("2003-05-25"));
    Criterion byname = Restrictions.eq("institution", new Institution().getTypeName()== "Education");

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(CreationDate.class)
                                                                    .add(Restrictions.and(bydate, byname)).list();


}
```

My entity one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CREATION_DATE")
@NamedQueries ({
@NamedQuery(name="creationDate.findById", query="select distinct c from CreationDate c left join fetch c.institution n " +
                                                  "left join fetch c.scheduleRotationChild s where c.dateId= :i"),
@NamedQuery(name="creationDate.findByDate", query="select distinct c from CreationDate c left join fetch c.institution i" +
        "left join fetch c.scheduleRotationChild s where c.particularDate= :date"),
@NamedQuery(name="creationDate.findAll", query="select distinct c from CreationDate c left join fetch c.institution n " +
                                                  "left join fetch c.scheduleRotationChild s ")
})
public class CreationDate implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1648102358397071136L;


    private int dateId;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="DATE_ID")
        public int getDateId() {
            return dateId;
        }

        public void setDateId(int dateId) {
            this.dateId = dateId;
        }


    private Date particularDate;

        @Column(name="PARTICULAR_DATE")
        public Date getParticularDate() {
            return particularDate;
        }

        public void setParticularDate(Date particularDate) {
            this.particularDate = particularDate;
        }


    private int version;

        @Version
        @Column(name="VERSION")
        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(int version) {
            this.version = version;
        }


    private Date childGoSchoolDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name="CHILD_GO_SCHOOL_DATE")
        public Date getChildGoSchoolDate() {
            return childGoSchoolDate;
        }

        public void setChildGoSchoolDate(Date childGoSchoolDate) {
            this.childGoSchoolDate = childGoSchoolDate;
        }


    private Date childAdmissionDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name="CHILD_ADMISSION_DATE")
        public Date getChildAdmissionDate() {
            return childAdmissionDate;
        }

        public void setChildAdmissionDate(Date childAdmissionDate) {
            this.childAdmissionDate = childAdmissionDate;
        }


    private Set<Institution> institution = new HashSet<Institution>();

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="CREATIONDATE_INSTITUTION", 
                                    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DATE_ID"), 
                                    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="INSTITUTION_ID"))
        public Set<Institution> getInstitution() {
            return institution;
        }

        public void setInstitution(Set<Institution> institutionSet) {
            this.institution = institutionSet;
        }


    private List<ScheduleRotationChild> scheduleRotationChild = new ArrayList<ScheduleRotationChild>();

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="SRC_DATE", 
                                    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DATE_ID"),
                                    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="SRC_ID"))
        public List<ScheduleRotationChild> getScheduleRotationChild() {
            return scheduleRotationChild;
        }

        public void setScheduleRotationChild(
                List<ScheduleRotationChild> scheduleRotationChild) {
            this.scheduleRotationChild = scheduleRotationChild;
        }





        public void addNameInstitution(Set<Institution> institution) {

            setInstitution(institution);

        }



        public void addSRC(List<ScheduleRotationChild> srcinstitution) {

        setScheduleRotationChild(srcinstitution);

        }


        public String toString() {

            return  dateId + " , " 
            + particularDate + " , " 
            + childGoSchoolDate + " , " 
            + childAdmissionDate + "  " + scheduleRotationChild ;

        }

}
```

My entity two:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INSTITUTION")
@NamedQuery(name="creationDate.findByName", query="select distinct i from Institution i left join fetch i.creationDate c " +
        "where i.institutionId= :i")
public class Institution implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7636394097858726922L;


    private int institutionId;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="INSTITUTION_ID")
        public int getInstitutionId() {
            return institutionId;
        }

        public void setInstitutionId(int institutionId) {
            this.institutionId = institutionId;
        }


    private int version;

        @Version
        @Column(name="VERSION")
        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(int version) {
            this.version = version;
        }


    private String nameOfInstitution;

        @Column(name="NAME_INSTITUTION")
        public String getNameOfInstitution() {
            return nameOfInstitution;
        }

        public void setNameOfInstitution(String nameOfInstitution) {
            this.nameOfInstitution = nameOfInstitution;
        }


    private String typeName;

        @Column(name="TYPE_NAME")
        public String getTypeName() {
            return typeName;
        }
        public void setTypeName(String typeName) {
            this.typeName = typeName;
        }


    private Set<CreationDate> creationDate = new HashSet<CreationDate>();

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy="institution", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
        public Set<CreationDate> getCreationDate() {
            return creationDate;
        }

        public void setCreationDate(
                Set<CreationDate> creationDateSet) {
            this.creationDate = creationDateSet;
        }


        public void addCreationDate(CreationDate cDate, Set<CreationDate> crDate, List<ScheduleRotationChild> src) {
            cDate.setScheduleRotationChild(src);
            setCreationDate(crDate);

        }


        public String toString() {

            return institutionId + " , " + nameOfInstitution + " , " + typeName ;

        }

}
```

Please give me some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am reading this right, but your SQL is producing

```
where (this_.PARTICULAR_DATE=? and this_.DATE_ID=?)
```

But your criteria is setting "institution" as a Boolean value

Comment: Hm?? But it does not help anyway. I can suppose that I haven't specify  the value for ID and it's does not know what to pick up for sorting or something.